# overloaded constructor illegal with move and copy

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, forwarding-reference

I have a class that I'm writing that will take a special type for one of its constructors that could be any type that fits my requirements. I have run into the issue that this templated constructor causes my copy and move constructors to be illegal overloads!

My class is layed out like this:

```
template<typename ... Types>
class myclass{
    public:
        myclass(const myclass &other){/* copy constructor */}
        myclass(myclass &&other){/* move constructor */}

        template<typename Special>
        myclass(Special &&arg){/* stops copy/move implementations */}
}
```

How can I get around this limitation?

Comment: I guess you mean that `myclass(Special &&arg)` is preferred to a copy constructor for a non-const lvalue argument?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki yeahp, I do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Constrain it.

```
template<typename Special,
         std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<std::decay_t<Special>, myclass>{}, int> = 0 >
myclass(Special &&arg) { /* ... */ }
```

Depending on your particular use case, you may also want to constrain `Special` further to only types that fit your requirements.

Comment: I have no idea why I just randomly forgot all about SFINAE. I'll accept this as the answer

Answer (score 0):

This example shows the different cases:

```
const myclass c1(42);      // special: int
myclass c2(c1);            // copy
myclass c3(c2);            // special: myclass& (non const)
myclass c4(std::move(c3)); // move
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/3lR5jo)

your copy/move constructors are still legal overloads, but non const l-value has an exact match with your template constructor.

You may:

- use SFINAE to forbid `myclass&` in the template (as in T.C's answer)
- provide an other overload (with exact match):

  ```
  myclass(myclass &other) : myclass(static_cast<const myclass &>(other)) {}
  ```

  [Demo](http://ideone.com/hFNlNh)

Comment: This seems like more of a comment than an answer

Comment: @CoffeeandCode: I was writing my answer by small parts.

Comment: That won't handle `myclass c5(std::move(c1));`.

Comment: @T.C.: Other overload for `const myclass&&` is possible. Not sure that this case has sense though...

Comment: @Jarod42 Generic code dealing with iterators, where you want to do something like `auto c = std::move(*it);` but have it still work with a const iterator.